# Better way to check if a NSdate is in a range

Tags: ios, nsdate

My App displays changes the value of an UILabel depending on the current date:

Current Implementation:

```
NSDate* todaysdate = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *week1startcomp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[week1startcomp setMonth:8];
[week1startcomp setDay:4];
[week1startcomp setYear:2014];
NSDate* week1start = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:week1startcomp];

NSDateComponents *week1endcomp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[week1endcomp setMonth:9];
[week1endcomp setDay:4];
[week1endcomp setYear:2014];
NSDate* week1end = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:week1endcomp];

NSDateComponents *week2startcomp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[week2startcomp setMonth:9];
[week2startcomp setDay:9];
[week2startcomp setYear:2014];
NSDate* week2start = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:week2startcomp];

NSDateComponents *week2endcomp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[week2endcomp setMonth:9];
[week2endcomp setDay:15];
[week2endcomp setYear:2014];
NSDate* week2end = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:week2endcomp];

NSDateComponents *week3startcomp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[week3startcomp setMonth:9];
[week3startcomp setDay:16];
[week3startcomp setYear:2014];
NSDate* week3start = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:week3startcomp];

NSDateComponents *week3endcomp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[week3endcomp setMonth:9];
[week3endcomp setDay:29];
[week3endcomp setYear:2014];
NSDate* week3end = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:week3endcomp];
```

and so on for 17 Weeks:

```
if([todaysdate compare:week1start] == NSOrderedDescending && [todaysdate compare:week1end]  == NSOrderedAscending){

    NSLog(@"Current week is Week 1");
    _currentWeekLabel.text = @"Currently in Week 1";

}else if([todaysdate compare:week2start] == NSOrderedDescending && [todaysdate compare:week2end]  == NSOrderedAscending){

    NSLog(@"Current week is Week 2");
     _currentWeekLabel.text = @"Currently in Week 2";

}else if([todaysdate compare:week3start] == NSOrderedDescending && [todaysdate compare:week3end]  == NSOrderedAscending){

    NSLog(@"Current week is Week 3");
     _currentWeekLabel.text = @"Currently in Week 3";
    }
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this? It currently works fine (with the exception of a logic issue for when a date lands on the first or last day of the range).

Any and all suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: You shouldn't have to hard-wire the dates like that.  NSDateComponents allows you to pick the week of the year.

Comment: Good point but these "weeks" don't always follow traditional weeks and can start on a Thursday and end on a Monday Night.

Comment: Then you should put the date info in a table so it's easier to edit.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure is almost same, it will help you with less code. Write a method like this:

```
- (BOOL)date:(NSDate*)date isBetweenDate:(NSDate*)beginDate andDate:(NSDate*)endDate
{
    if ([date compare:beginDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
        return NO;

    if ([date compare:endDate] == NSOrderedDescending) 
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Then do this:

```
if([self date:todaysdate isBetweenDate:week1start andDate:week1end]){

    NSLog(@"Current week is Week 1");
    _currentWeekLabel.text = @"Currently in Week 1";

}else if([self date:todaysdate isBetweenDate:week2start andDate:week2end]){

    NSLog(@"Current week is Week 2");
     _currentWeekLabel.text = @"Currently in Week 2";

}else if([self date:todaysdate isBetweenDate:week3start andDate:week3end]){

    NSLog(@"Current week is Week 3");
     _currentWeekLabel.text = @"Currently in Week 3";
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the speedy response. Is there an easier way to declare a date instead of using the NSDateComponents? or can I just do NSdate week1start = 09-04-2014. I think thats how I ended up having to use so much code.